# Opening personal geodatabases (*.mdb) in QGIS 3.4.1?

Tags: qgis, personal-geodatabase

I was successfully able to open *.mdbs in my previous version of QGIS on Windows 10 64 bit, but since the Madeira update (3.4.1, 64 bit) they no longer work.

Getting a "Layer is not valid" error with no given reason.

I have added them as custom variables through QGIS:

```
OGR_SKIP 
value: ODBC

PGEO_DRIVER_TEMPLATE
value: DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);DBQ=%s
```

I've tried adding these variables in through Windows advanced systems settings/environments as well, same variables as above.

Gone through multiple restarts and combinations of variable settings.

Microsoft Access database engine (64) is installed.

Is it the update? Am I doing something wrong?

Alternatively, is there another way to access ESRI personal geodatabases through QGIS? I haven't been successful using any other methods I've found so far but any tips would be great!

Comment: Please edit your question to include a summary of what other methods you've tried. Otherwise people will suggest things you've already tried, and that's a waste of your time and theirs.

Comment: @Luke updated to add info!

Comment: @Luke 64 bit for sure